# How to add a marker on a groundoverlay by a click?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markers

I developed a map application using gmap2. I used a groundoverlay (a temperature map) to help users to determine the location of interest and click to select. After gmap2 being replaced by gmap3, it stops working. The bigger problem is that I could not find a way to add markers on the groundoverlay by clicking in gmap3. Someone raised a similar question, but no answer has been available. I hope that such a function is not lost in gmap3. Your help is appreciated.

```
enter code here

<script>
var map;
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(54.508742, -125.120850);
var pngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(48.3367, -139.0402), 
                    new google.maps.LatLng(59.99008, -114.1095));

function initialize() {
     var mapProp = { center: mapCenter, zoom: 5, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
     var groundoverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
        "http://www.genetics.forestry.ubc.ca/cfcg/ClimateBC40/overlays/climate/MAT_1961_1990.png", pngBounds);
     groundoverlay.setMap(map);
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) { placeMarker(event.latLng); });
}

    function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: location, map: map, draggable: true });
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: code has been added above

Answer (score 1):

In v3 you have to make the `groundOverlay` non-clickable

```
var groundoverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    "http://www.genetics.forestry.ubc.ca/cfcg/ClimateBC40/overlays/climate/MAT_1961_1990.png", pngBounds, **{clickable:false}**);
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code as simple as that..

```
let overlayGeoMapImg = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
  '../assets/GNDVI.png',
  imageBounds);
  overlayGeoMapImg.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(overlayGeoMapImg, 'click', (event: any) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    });
  });
```